# Did Zetsu know about Tobi's truth/identity all the time?

Tags: naruto

I'm guessing Zetsu is one of

> Madara Uchiha's successful projects (created from First Hokage's DNA)!

And that makes me believe that

> Obito and Zetsu must be knowing each other!

But on the contrary! When Tobi was searching Sasori's ring (after his fight with Chiyo and Sakura), if you observe Black Zetsu and White Zetsu's comments on Tobi, one would think that they weren't aware of Tobi's serious part of life.

Comment: what is the reason for downvoting??

Comment: I edited your title to prevent spoilers. Also, I think that **if you have the information on the first spoiler markup, you also know the answer to your own question**. When that info (the one on the first spoiler markup) is given (chapter 606), one already knows that Zetsu and Tobi (his alter-ego, actually) had interacted (in chapter 603), with the former helping the latter.

Comment: @JNat, I see, thanks for responding. will take of spoilers in future :)

Comment: If you know Tobi's identity, then you almost certainly know the answer to your question, since Tobi's backstory was covered about 2-3 chapters after his identity was revealed. So unless **you answered your own question**, I fail to understand why you needed to ask this.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai, thanks for a downvote! Well. It is possible that obito might have cleared Zetsu's brain, as his intentions were more clear than his methodologies, which he never cared about. I wanted to know because I wanted to be sure if he was really acting or he was being controlled. Tobi has done it to many since past!

Comment: @Sai I did not downvote.

Comment: k. Sorry for claiming it then :) There were many zetsu clones created prior to White/Black zetsu with same shape and powers! The ones created by madara may not be the same who are existing now. Tobi himself knew the technique, so he might have created one himself. But not revealing them his true identity! I suspected that I might have missed a part somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zetsu *did* know Tobi from the beginning.

> Tobi has interacted with the White Zetsu the moment he arrived to Madara's cave. Black Zetsu was created by Madara in Obito's presence.

The reason for Zetsu supposedly not knowing Tobi could be

1. He wanted to keep it hidden from the other Akatsuki members.
2. Kishimoto haven't thought about it at the time.

Comment: accepted for adding 2nd point :)

Comment: Do you remember this thread? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158016/should-the-voting-be-locked-for-question-that-is-closed/158023#158023 we had long discussion out there :)

Comment: @Sai: I don't understand how it related to the topic in hand though.

Comment: sorry! it isn't related .. but wanted to point out that we met earlier :)

Comment: @Sai: Oh, cool :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, he did. It is shown in chapter 603 (on the very first page) that Zetsu was given the opportunity to look after

> Obito while he was recovering.

Comment: so he was just acting as if he didn't know .. (just to hide it from other members of Akatsuki)

Comment: @Sai, yes, exactly ;)

Answer (score -1):

It was clearly a retcon. And NOBODY above answered his question...just gave bs info pertaining to after they retconned tobi. Black zetsu in the anime...not manga...does not know tobi's identity and "bosses" him around like a recruit even though there is nobody else there to "fool". Deidara comes a few minutes after tobi loses the ring. The only answer is this was very clearly retconned into just being obito. Ive watched the show 6 times over in 6 months. Its the greatest show ever made. That doesnt mean they didnt need a retcon or two. The mods of this thread are idiots. The show has been over for gd years....dont need a spoiler alert ffs.